# Call a mongo nodejs script in intervals to update view

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb module for nodejs. I am trying to retrieve some values from mongo collection and rendering on view. View used is ejs and express framework for nodejs. Data in mongo is populated in a stream.So there is continuous flow of data. And I want to auto refresh the view at intervals by querying mongo collection and rendering on view to get latest data.More like ajax call or Server sent events does.I have looked around for the approach. But i am not sure how to do SSE for mongo query and rendering the view. Can some one guide me how to tackle this one.

Comment: Did you try something? Could you share your code?

Comment: @SachinShetty Did [my post below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634229/call-a-mongo-nodejs-script-in-intervals-to-update-view/39635973#39635973) answer your question? If it did then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) because right now other people searching for this problem see that your question has no good answer and may not read it. If it didn't answer your question then please comment on what is missing. I'm going through my old answers and I want to make sure they're good. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways in which you can do that. You can make periodical queries from the browser, you can use WebSocket, Socket.IO, server-sent events. You can either poll for new data on the server and notify the client, you can also poll from the client and initiate the new database lookup on the server. You can even do an ordinary page that doesn't refresh and add `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` to the HTML to have it refreshed every 5 seconds. There are so many ways that you can do it that it's pretty much impossible to give you any specific answer. It all depends on how are you going to use it, whether you want to do it quickly, what traffic does it need to handle, what technologies are you using right now, what have you tried so far, etc.